# Meaning of certain identities of Gauss on theta functions

Tags: mathematics, gauss

Volume 3 of Gauss's werke contains an unpublished treatise with the title "***Theory of new transcendents***" (p.433-481 of the same volume), whose writing is dated, according to the editor Schering, to 1808; Schering states that those investigations prompted a communication to Schumacher. On page 441 of the same volume appears an interesting identity on theta functions which i suspect is a result of Gauss which i tried to locate in his writings for a very long time. The simplest way to describe it is to quote Gauss:

> The division of seven leads to the following  equation:
> $$b = (\frac{1-2x+2x^4-...}{1+2x+2x^4+...})^2$$
> $$A = (\frac{1+2x^7+2x^{28}+...}{1+2x+2x^4+...})^2$$
> $$B = (\frac{1-2x^7+2x^{28}-...}{1+2x+2x^4+...})^2$$
> then:
> $$A^8-\frac{4}{7}A^6+\frac{16-32b^2}{49}A^5-\frac{30}{343}A^4+\frac{32-64b^2}{2401}A^3-\frac{2+768b^2-768b^4}{16807}A^2+\frac{48-2144b^2+6144b^4-4096b^6}{823543}A -\frac{1}{823543} = 0$$
> If we replace $b^2$ with $1-b^2$ and $A$ with $-A$, the expression for $A$ is unchanged.

Gauss's fragment contains a similar result for $B$ but i didn't want to write it (it's very similar to the result for $A$). Note also that the denominators in all of the terms are powers of $7$.

Rewriting Gauss's indentities in modern notation:
$$b = (\frac{\theta_4(0,x)}{\theta_3(0,x)})^2$$
$$A = (\frac{\theta_3(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x)})^2$$
$$B = (\frac{\theta_4(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x)})^2$$

where $\theta_3(0,x)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n^2},\theta_4(0,x) = 1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{n^2}$ are Jacobi's theta functions. Then Gauss found an inhomogenous algebraic (polynomial) expression $P(A,b) = 0$. This long presentation of Gauss's fragment was intended to present his results as accurate as possible. In a previous post ([Question about Hermite's 1858 solution to the quintic equation using elliptic modular functions and it's relation to Gauss' and Jacobi's work](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/question-about-hermites-1858-solution-to-the-quintic-equation-using-elliptic-mo/11564#11564)), one of my questions was where Gauss's modular transformation of order 7 (according to some books, modular transformations of order 3,5 and 7 were known to Gauss since 1808). This fragment of Gauss deals with theta functions (not elliptic integrals), but since elliptic integrals and theta functions are related, i suspect this is the identity i searched for.

Therefore, my questions are:

- Can anyone familiar with the theory of elliptic integrals (and theta functions) confirm that is the so-called modular transformation of order 7?
- does this identity contain arithmetical information? i ask that because on another previous post ([Did Gauss know Jacobi's four squares theorem?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/did-gauss-know-jacobis-four-squares-theorem)) i refered to another identity of Gauss (on p.445 in the same treatise) on an expansion of $\theta_3^4(0,x)$ in infinite series, and this identity does yield arithmetic information (namely Jacobi's four squares theorem).

And i apologize once again about my endless questioning about Gauss (i simply can't find references to many results in his writings...)!

Comment: In order to aim those who want to help me, i think that in order to answer this question one needs, as a first step, to search for identities related to "lifting"  of theta functions from $q$ to $q^n$, i. e to express $\theta(0,q^n)$ in terms of $\theta(0, q) $. I tried to search for a textbook on such "liftings" but i didn't find anything.

Comment: The identities for "lifting" is very similar to my "Dedekind eta-function product identities". Let $\,t_n:=θ_3(0,q^n).\,$ Verify that $\,2\,t_4^2 − 2\,t_4t_1 + t_1^2 − t_2^2 = 3\,t_9^3t_1 − 3\,t_9^2t_1^2 + t_9t_1^33 − t_3^4 = 0.\,$ These are just examples of many such identities and not hard to find with a algebraic relation finding tool.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas mentioned in Gauss's note are not the modular equation of order 7, but a very close one; the formula for $A$ is in fact the "**Multiplier equation**" .The point is that confirming that $P(B,b) = 0$ (not $P(A,b)$; the equation $P(B,b) = 0$ was not written by me in the posted question) is the modular equation of order 7 would be much easier, and the answer would be yes, if only Gauss would define $B$ to be $(\frac{\theta_4(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x^7)})^2$ instead of $(\frac{\theta_4(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x)})^2$. To show the equivalency with the so-called "Transformation problem" of elliptic integrals, let us recall a few definitions and facts.

**Definitions**:

- The nome $q$ of a theta function is denoted $x$ in Gauss fragment.
- The modulus $k$ of a complete elliptic integral of the first kind is the constant parameter in
  $K(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2sin^2(\phi)}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-kt^2)}} $. The complementary modulus is defined to be $k' = \sqrt{1-k^2}$.
- A complete elliptic integral of the first kind can be written as quotient of theta functions. The complementary elliptic modulus $k'$ can be written as: $(\frac{\theta_4(0,q)}{\theta_3(0,q)})^2$ where the nome $q$ is $e^{-\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}}$.
- The transformation problem, or the problem of modular equation determination, is for one modulus $k$, to find a second modulus $l$ such that $\frac{K(l')}{K(l)} = n\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

**The modular equation of order n**:

Using the third fact, one can write $(\frac{\theta_4(0,q^n)}{\theta_3(0,q^n)})^2 = (\frac{\theta_4(0,e^{-n\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}})}{\theta_3(0,e^{-n\pi\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}})})^2$. Rewriting $n\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}$ as $\frac{K(l')}{K(l)}$, one gets that $(\frac{\theta_4(0,q^n)}{\theta_3(0,q^n)})^2$ is nothing else than $l'$. Therefore an implicit relation between $k' = (\frac{\theta_4(0,q)}{\theta_3(0,q)})^2$ and $l' = (\frac{\theta_4(0,q^n)}{\theta_3(0,q^n)})^2$ is indeed the modular equation of order $n$: $P(k',l')=0$.

**The connection to Gauss's fragment:**

Unfortunately, as i remarked in the begining, Gauss defines $B$ to be $(\frac{\theta_4(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x)})^2$ so the whole argument doesn't correspond to Gauss's note. However, since he states the results for both $A$ and $B$, and since $\frac{B}{A} = (\frac{\theta_4(0,x^7)}{\theta_3(0,x^7)})^2$, one can say that at least numericaly, Gauss's results enable to determine $l'$ in terms of $k'$.

**The relation of Gauss's fragment to the "multiplier equation":**

According to p.512 volume 2 of the book series "Die elliptischen Funktionen und ihre Anwendungen" by Robert Fricke, the correct "Multiplikator gleichungen" (german for: "Multiplier equation") of order 7 is:

$$M^8 - 28M^6 + 112(1-2k^2)M^5 - 210M^4 + 224(1-2k^2)M^3 - (140+5376k^2k'^2)M^2 + (1-2k^2)(48-2048k^2k'^2)M - 7 = 0$$

Subsituting $M = 7A$ in the correct equation and dividing by $7^8 = 7\cdot 823543$, one gets Gauss's equation. So it's 99% certain that Gauss's formula is in fact the multiplier equation. The only thing i don't understand is why $M = 7A$ - according to all sources i found $M$ is supposed to be equal to $A$.